# Linearly ordered, non CT-groups

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

A **linearly ordered group** is a group $(G,\dot,1)$ together with a linear ordering $<$ on $G$ with $f<g \Longrightarrow (f h<g h$ and $h f < h g)$ for all $f,g,h \in G$.

A **commutative-transitive group (or CT-group)** is a group $(G,\dot,1)$ in which two elements which commute with a third, non-trivial one, commute together. Equivalently, this is a group in which centralizers are commutative.

I'm having a hard time finding linearly ordered groups whose underlying group is not a CT-group, but I see no reason why any linearly ordered group should be a CT-group. Are there ways to construct linearly ordered *non* CT-groups?

Comment: To be sure I understand what you are asking, from what you wrote in the 2nd to last sentence I infer that you can neither prove nor disprove that linear orderability implies CT. From that, I was expecting you to ask for constructions of linearly ordered groups that *are not* CT. Nonetheless, you are asking for constructions of linearly ordered groups that *are* CT, correct?

Comment: @LeeMosher Your intuition was good, and my attention is not. I meant non CT-groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such groups are often called "bi-orderable".

Torsion-free nilpotent groups are all bi-orderable.

But a non-abelian nilpotent group is never commutative-transitive.

Hence, every non-abelian torsion-free nilpotent group yields an example (bi-orderable, not commutative-transitive).

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice answer.